# style modification glossaries-extra.sty help

Tags: spacing, formatting, glossaries-extra

My codes are follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries-extra}

\newglossaryentry{valid}
{
  name={valid},
  description={An argument is valid just in case its premises provide
    decisive support for its conclusion, alternatively, if the truth
    of its premises guarantees the truth of its conclusion.} }

\newglossaryentry{atomic sentence} { name={atomic sentence},
  first={\emph{atomic sentence}},
  description={An atomic sentence is a sentence that does not have any
    other sentence as a proper syntactic part.  In propositional
    logic, atomic sentences are represented by capital letters such as
    $P,Q,R,\dots $.  In quantifier logic, the atomic sentences are
    either relation symbols applied to closed terms, such as $Rab$, or equalities between closed terms, such as $a=b$.}
}


\newglossaryentry{interpretation}
{
  name={interpretation},
  description={An interpretation is an assignment of symbols to set-theoretic structures.}
}

\newglossaryentry{turnstile}% label
{
  name={\ensuremath{\alpha}},% default display
  description={The relation of provability defined by the inference rules.},% description
  category=symbol% category label
}

\makeglossaries
\begin{document}

  An argument is said to be \gls{valid} if its premises imply
  its conclusion. \gls{atomic sentence}


An \textbf{\gls{interpretation}} of the symbols in $\Sigma$ consists symbol
\gls{turnstile}

\printglossaries

\end{document}
```

I've marked my requirement below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`description` environment is used for the glossary entries, now I can meet the requirement...

Comment: is this an answer to your own question?

Comment: Yes, I met my requirement after modify the `description` environment...